# How to design a database when product has variable attributes with different prices

Tags: database

Hi I am doing a website for a printing shop, their product's attributes are not limited to like 'name/description/price', actually there are a number of factors affect the price, 'color/size/material/frame etc'.

Every different combination of these has a different price, and they may add or remove some attributes in future, which make me can not simply create a product table with all the fixed attributes in.

I am thinking about using a tag table holds all the attributes as records, and still not sure where to put the price.

Anyone has any experience in this situation? Any ideas how to get this modeled in database?

Comment: This could be an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) design - take a look online about this design, including it's advantages and disadvantages. You might find your next challenge is building a system that allows them to define complex pricing models, for example lower unit prices at higher volumes

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 tables

1. Products

   - All data related to product (ProductId, Name, ...)
2. Tags

   - All of your attributes (TagId, Name, ...)
3. ProductTags

   - The attributes each product has with the price (ProductId, TagId, Price)

[image]

Comment: thanks but one product can have more than one tag, and each combination has a different price, for example 'full color - A4 - Canvas '  or 'blackwhite - A1 - paper' etc, not just one tag, so i dont think that mapping table will work

Comment: With the following map you can have many products with many tags with different prices. As you can see in the ERD, you have many to many relation between products and tags.

Comment: yeah, i know it is a many to many, the thing is i can not attach price to one particular record(ProductTag), because the price it is determined by multiple tag, and one tag can appear in more than one combination, take 'full color - A4 - Canvas $99' for expample, there are 3 tags in it ' color - size - material', i can not put price to any of it because it is not deiced by any of them alone.

Comment: Hi @KevinMa, how did you solve this issue? I am curious, as I also want to design for similar requirements. Is there any one, who has tackled variable pricing based on combination of multiple price tags and specification attributes, i.e for (height > 10 inch, color = red) price is $50, for (height > 10 inch, color = white) price is $53 and for (height < 10 inch, sleeve = False) price is $23?

Comment: It may also have multipliers for the tags/attributes, rather than having direct prices or simple additions like 1.5 times or 0.3 times?